# Howto set paper size using postscript() to make it same with pdf() in R

Tags: r, plot

I have already successfully plot a figure using this command:

```
pdf("myplot.pdf",paper="a4",height=20.0)
```

The figures are well placed with the proper size orientation 
and size. But when I convert it to postcript with the same
parameter, it goes wrong.

```
postscript("myplot.eps",paper="a4",height=20.0)
```

What's the correct way to set the parameter in `postscript()`
so that it generate the same format as `pdf()`?

Comment: the docs would suggest that you should set the `width` as well, as they have different default values in `pdf` and `postscript`. And I would forget about `paper="a4"` and use `"special"` in both cases; it's much less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you really to use [`knitr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr). One of the motivation of the package is :

> I wished for many times that if only I could use graphics devices
>   other than PDF and postscript; now the dream has come true in the
>   official R, but what I was hoping for was an option as simple as dev =
>   'png' or dev = 'CairoJPEG'.

For example you can create a chunck

```
<<dev='postscript'>>=
   plot(cars)  ##replace this by your code to create myplot
@
```